# installing aws API on symfony2

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, installation, composer-php

I am working on a project under symfony 2.1
We need to install and use AWS API (for using cloud with PHP/CURL).
So I follow [these insctructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssdkdocsphp2/latest/gettingstartedguide/sdk-php2-installing-the-sdk.html)
I choose composer for installing the SDK ('cause symfony already use composer).

The download of the sources file have worked, and in my vendor directory I got the AWS sources.
But in my code source, all the classes of amazon returns an error ("Fatal Error : Class [...] not found [...]"

So I think the problem comes that symfony dont load the sources files.
I try to search on the internet, and I try to find a way alone (looking on files etc ...)

But I didnt find any way to load the sources files.
I try to add on the AppKernerl the build directory of SDK. Nothing happens.
I try to require_once a file named (phar-stub.php, in the build directory).
Error show up.

Can someone help me please,

Answer (score 2):

You may use Symfony2 bundle which simply wraps offical AWS SDK  - https://github.com/seferov/aws-bundle

After configuring the bundle, you can call aws clients as simple as this:

```
// ...
public function indexAction()
{
    $ec2 = $this->get('aws.ec2');
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `use` statements in your class definition. Imported classes will be automatically loaded.

For example:

```
  <?php
   namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

   use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

   class DefaultController
   {
      function indexAction(){
          $ec2 = new Ec2Client();
          ....
      }

   }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php
http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime Aws has created an official bundle that takes care of the issue:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony